# Mobile site footer anchor to "full site" does not have cursor as pointer

Tags: bug, design

From the main site Stack Overflow, there is a link in the footer to 'mobile', which, when clicked, displays the page as a mobile page. The resulting mobile page footer has a link back to 'full site'. All the other links in the footer show the cursor as 'pointer' when hovered except this link.

Am I correct in assuming that this is due to the footer anchor html missing a href?

```
<a onclick=" StackExchange.switchMobile('off') ">full site</a>
```

which should (apparently) be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="StackExchange.switchMobile('off')">full site</a>
```

Also, (to be picky) would I be correct in saying that there are unnecessary spaces in the onclick="" script?

This is seen using Chrome v63.0.3239.84 on windows OS.

Comment: Why would a link on a site meant for mobile devices need to have a pointer explicitly set on links? Mobile devices don't have cursors.

Comment: @animuson By that logic, there shouldn't be a "Mobile" link in the footer here, since desktop devices don't need the mobile site. But the link exists, and therefore gets clicked, and then the path back to full site is a link without an expected attribute.

Comment: @CrazyIvan Not even close. Sometimes mobile devices aren't correctly identified as mobile and end up on the full site. *That's* why the link exists. It's not there for people to switch back and forth on desktops and we don't support people doing that.

Comment: I get, but there is a link (like the one at the bottom of this page) which is there to be clicked on the desktop site, and it just looks "incomplete" for the desktop user if you want to click to get back to the main site, not least because the other anchors show cursor: pointer.